# How can I create a grouped barplot with NA data in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to plot a grouped barplot using a data.frame with two columns:

```
modifications1 | modifications2 
UNIMOD:730     |      NA
UNIMOD:4       | UNIMOD:4
UNIMOD:214     |UNIMOD:214
UNIMOD:21      |UNIMOD:21
UNIMOD:35      |UNIMOD:35
UNIMOD:4       |UNIMOD:4
UNIMOD:4       |UNIMOD:4
UNIMOD:4       |     NA
NA             |UNIMOD:35
         ... n
```

This is an example of what I wish, but with the name of each row in the label.

[image]

Here you have a reproducible example:

```
df <- data.frame(modifications1=c("UNIMOD:108","UNIMOD:200","UNIMOD:300","UNIMOD:400","UNIMOD:108","UNIMOD:108","UNIMOD:108","UNIMOD:108","UNIMOD:600"), modifications2=c(NA,"UNIMOD:200","UNIMOD:300","UNIMOD:400","UNIMOD:108","UNIMOD:108","UNIMOD:108",NA,"UNIMOD:600"))
```

I couldn't find any example like mine in this page.

I have tried to use this:

```
    table1 <- data.frame(table(dataprueba$modifications.1))
table2 <- data.frame(table(dataprueba$modifications.2))

ggplot(NULL, aes(Var1, Freq)) + 
    geom_bar(aes(fill = "table1"), data = table1, alpha = 0.5, stat="identity") +
    geom_bar(aes(fill = "table2"), data = table2, alpha = 0.5, stat="identity") +
    guides(fill=FALSE)+ 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

But this is not what I really want it.

Comment: @Axeman Sorry, I sent the questions without writing what I'm using. xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `melt` your data set and then make a bar plot with `count` stat:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
ggplot(melt(df,measure.vars = names(df)), aes(x = value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "count", position = "dodge") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 20, hjust = 0.5, vjust = -0.1)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('#C73200', '#0072B2'))
```

[image]